# Material-ui Data Grid. What is the reason for rendering header with "number" type aligned to the right and how to make it looks like for other types?

Tags: material-ui

As you can see here https://codesandbox.io/s/92qje, the render of numeric columns (i.e. "Age") has differences in alignment (aligned to the right) in comparison to other columns (aligned to the left). That is why these 2 questions raise for me.

1. Does such alignment increase UX? If so, why?
2. How to make it render in the same way as other columns?

   - There are properties `headerAlign` and `align` for column definition https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/rendering/#styling-header, but after setting these value to the "left" the menu dots does not change its position.

Comment: Setting both `align: "left"` and `headerAlign: "left"` works for me. You are missing `headerAlign` in the code sandbox, maybe that's why? If not, removing `type: "number"` works too.